# Make YouTube video autoplay using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, youtube

I am trying to make my video autoplay using react. adding `autoplay=1` as a parameter doesn't work. Any suggestions?`

Here is my code.

```
<div
  className="video mt-5"
  style={{
         position: "relative",
         paddingBottom: "56.25%" /* 16:9 */,
         paddingTop: 25,
         height: 0
       }}
>
    <iframe
       style={{
             position: "absolute",
             top: 0,
             left: 0,
             width: "100%",
             height: "100%"
             }}
        src={'https://www.youtube.com/embed/hEnr6Ewpu_U?'}
        frameBorder="0"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: _“adding autoplay=1 as a paramter doesnt work”_ - then you are perhaps trying this in an environment where it isn’t _supposed to_ in the first place? In mobile browsers, attempts to autoplay are usually blocked, and explicit user interaction is required to start playback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to 2018 changes in youtube policies, they've omitted option to autoplay videos with sound. If you want to autoplay it muted, there's still an option to do it with an iframe:

```
<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/hEnr6Ewpu_U?autoplay=1&mute=1'
        frameBorder='0'
        allow='autoplay; encrypted-media'
        allowFullScreen
        title='video'
/>
```

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't use `<iframe>` cuz when you go to Youtube you still have to click to play. I would use a library called react-player

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

<ReactPlayer
  url={props.url}
  playing={true}
  width={props.width}
  height={props.height}
/>
```

And it will autoplay :)

Comment: playing true is not get you autoplay but if you add muted true this will work perfectly
Ref:https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/22/17150870/google-chrome-autoplay-videos-sound-mute-update

Comment: Regular HTML to get Autoplay to work was not working for my React project, but using ReactPlayer did it!!

Answer (score 0):

## This solved it for me

If you are using `<video>` in react

- Use `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay` for react.
- Also add `muted`

`<video autoPlay muted src="/vid.mp4" />`

if you want to use the `autoplay` with small letters, you should assign the value `autoplay="true"`